# ANSI C programming

Tags: c, ansi-c

On page 69 from ANSI C programming by K&R  there is an example of a function that works as a  special version of Unix program grep.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000 //max input length

int getlinee(char line[], int max); 

int Strindex(char source[], char searchfor[]); 

char pattern[] = "ould"; 

int main ()

{ 

    char line[MAXLINE];
    int found =0; 
    while (getlinee(line,MAXLINE) > 0)
        if (Strindex(line, pattern)>=0){
        printf("%s", line); 
        found ++; 
        }
    return found;
} // end of main function


int  getlinee (char s[], int lim) 
{ 

    int c,i; 
    i =0; 
    while (--lim > 0 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c!= '\n')
        s[i++] =c; 
    if (c =='\n')
        s[i++] =c; 
    s[i] = '\0' ; 
    return i; 
} 



int Strindex (char s[], char t[])
{ 

    int i,j,k; 
    for (i =0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        for (i =i, k=0; t[k] != '\0' && s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++); 
        if (k > 0 && t[k] == '\0')
        return i;

    }
   return -1; 



    } // end of strindex
```

when I compile it I get

```
51:1:error: expected identifier or '(' before 'return'
54:1:error: expected identifier or '(' before '}' token
```

I checked the code number of times and couldn't spot out the error.

Comment: This code snippet is broken. The #include without a header name won't compile. Please fix this and get rid of all the useless empty lines.

Comment: Hint: I just tried to put your code into proper indenting. Turns out this makes the error immediately obvious, so I leave it to you. **Always** take care to indent properly, **always** use `{}` even for one-line blocks of `if` or `for` or `while`. Even for an empty block, put `{}` and a comment line `// EMPTY` to make things explicit. This requires discipline, but is an *invaluable* habit to get in.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your extra

```
return -1; 

} // end of strindex
```

Also you `#include` is empty.You are not using any header file.

Comment: The include was OK, he just used faulty formatting in the post.

Comment: You can't remove `return`, function should return some value. Even if it pass compile, it would give unexpected result.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code.
(i). Line number 40:

```
for (i = i, k = 0; t[k] != '\0' && s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++)
```

Compiler may raise an error for `i = i` as `Assignment to itself 'i = i'`

(ii). Line number 45:
An extra `}`. Delete this. Then try to build. I make changes your code and it successfully built.

```
     #include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000 //max input length
int getlinee(char line[], int max);

int Strindex(char source[], char searchfor[]);

char pattern[] = "ould";

int main()

{

    char line[MAXLINE];
    int found = 0;
    while (getlinee(line, MAXLINE) > 0)
        if (Strindex(line, pattern) >= 0) {
            printf("%s", line);
            found++;
        }
    return found;
} // end of main function

int getlinee(char s[], int lim) {

    int c, i;
    i = 0;
    while (--lim > 0 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

int Strindex(char s[], char t[]) {

    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        for (i = 1, k = 0; t[k] != '\0' && s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++)
            ;
    if (k > 0 && t[k] == '\0')
        return i;

return -1;

} // end of strindex
```

Answer (score 0):

If we judge by indent and code structure, I think there's open parentheses missing in line:

```
for (i =0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

in last function. So the actual line should look like:

```
for (i =0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
```

There are more than one error in last function. Another one is that `j` is not initialized.
As I can conclude, that function should search for index of substring inside string. First loop passes through string `s`. Second loop passes through second string and compares two strings. If comparison reaches the end of second string, it returns found index, else function exits with index `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 }
return -1;
```

Remove `}` brace above line with `return` operator.

Comment: Minor note: `return` is not an operator.

Comment: @unwind Is it better to call this _statement_?

Comment: Yes, it's a statement.